# Bootstrap button not aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have simple form from some tutorial but it doesn't work on my side

Why this button is not aligned ?

http://jsfiddle.net/9czbdLqp/1/

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

    <br/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>First Page</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstNameInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">First Name</label>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastNameInput" class="control-label col-sm-3">Last Name</label>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: What should it be alligned with the text boxes or the legend?

Comment: It should be aligned with inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formgroup div's are being inset with a negative margin from bootstrap's css

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
   margin-right: -15px;
   margin-left: -15px;
}
```

you can wrap your submit in a form group or remove the margins on the div

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wgoxLn2/1/

Comment: and how can I fix it ? by the way that strange, because I took this from some tutorial and guy showed that it should be aligned.

Comment: just wrap your submit in a form group

Comment: I updated my answer with a fiddle to reflect how to fix this